# How to use javascript to select (a) child(ren) element(s) of a hovered element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

assuming I have a (very large) div tag and inside the div tag I have a (normal size) button, now I want to be able to create a shortcut that if a user is hovering over the div tag, they can press return key to click the button.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == xxx) {
    $('div').hover(function(){
      $('this button').click();
    });
  }
});
```

This is how I imagine it might look like in jQuery (didn't work obviously). I am open to suggestions. jQuery solutions are fine, plain javascript solutions are even better.

Comment: @JamesMontagne You are right. That was misleading, so I have removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == xxx) {
    $('div:hover button').click();
  }
});
```

Don't use .hover() or .on('hover') because they are simply not selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is(":hover")` within your keypress handler to determine if the proper div is being hovered:

```
$(window).keypress(function(){
    if($("#target").is(":hover")){
       alert("pressed!"); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7joukzw/2/
(NOTE: Make sure you click within the "result" frame to ensure it is the active frame when testing the jsfiddle)

Comment: Hey I am familiar with is('hover'), but I am not certain how I could use it to select the child element of a hovered element. Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking for hover on every keypress, you're better off reversing the order of event checking so that you only incur the keypress overhead while the user is hovering. Something like:

```
function checkKeypress(e) {
    // Check keypress and perhaps do something
}
$('div').hover(
    function(){
        $(window).keypress(checkKeypress);
    },
    function() {
        $(window).off('keypress', checkKeypress);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hey! Good thinking! My problem is that I would have say hundreds of these elements. So if I used $('div').hover() it would not give me the particular div that is being hovered. Do you think there is a work around for that?

Comment: jQuery lets you pass data to an event handler, so that if the div had some identifying information like ID or a data-something attribute, you could get that and pass it by "$(window).keypress(identifier, function(...". Your event handler could then do something specific to that div.